# How to add an animated splash screen using ionic 2?

Tags: cordova, ionic2, splash-screen

I have been building an ionic 2 app, so I want to add an interactive splash screen. Someone knows a plugin to do that?

Comment: may be not possible, refer this link -> https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/splash-screen-with-animation/50765

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/Wlttul?p=preview (taken from link above) Is animating before the app loads. This can be used if you disable ionic's default splash screen in the config file

Answer (score 0):

Think you can take a look at :

https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-an-animated-splash-screen-in-ionic/

A way to replace default splash screen with your own.

Regards

Comment: In this case it's not your fault because the question was off-topic, but please note that in general, an answer that recommends some tool or library must demonstrate how it solves the problem at hand in the answer itself.